# Autohotkey not loading MS Teams

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, microsoft-teams

I am trying to run an AHK script to open/show/minimize teams depending on the state of the app. I currently have the same functionality work for the windows calculator, but when I copy/paste the same solution, AHK fails to run teams. Currently, this is what I am working with

```
F11::
If WinExist("Teams ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow") 
{
    IfWinActive
        WinMinimize
    Else
    {
        WinGet, winState, MinMax
        If (winState = -1)
        {
            WinRestore
            WinActivate
        }
    }
}
Else 
{
    run ahk_exe Teams.exe
    WinWait, Teams
    WinActivate
}
return
```

however, it seems line 24 (`run ahk_exe Teams.exe`) is causing the issue. When I run windowSpy, I get the following:

[image: WindowSpy UI]

When I replace `ahk_exe Teams.exe` with `ahk_pid 6440` I get the same issues. Has anyone else had this issue and found a way around it?

Answer (score 4):

I feel like some of these terms need to be cleared up a bit:

`ahk_exe` is the name of the executable file (i.e. `.exe`) that the process is associated with. Normally, just using the [`run`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) command generically with the name of this file would do nothing, as AHK has no idea which folder this `.exe` is in. This *just happened* to work with the Windows Calculator app [`calc.exe`], since that was a program that Windows *allows* you to run anywhere you want. The solution is to tell `ahk` which folder the `.exe` is in so that it can run it.

If you want to test whether or not a specific program parameter for the [`run`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) command will work properly, you can open up a command prompt window and try the command, replacing AHK's [`run`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) with the Commandline's [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) [ex: `run calc.exe` becomes `start calc.exe`].

Additionally, `ahk_pid` is not a constant number that persistently associates with a program. In fact, every time you run a program, even if it is the same exact program, Windows will assign a new PID to it every time. Futhermore, because a new one is assigned after the program is launched, we cannot use it to initially launch a program.

---

**Important!: This code immediately below is unsafe and can corrupt your installation of Teams. Please see Update 1 for more info and a better alternative.**

Here is a solution that launches the Teams app (`Teams.exe`) from the default installation location in `C:\Users\[YOUR USER NAME HERE]\appdata\local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe`

```
run "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe"
```

---

Hope this was helpful. If you have any additional questions, please lmk

---

---

## Update 1:

While looking back at my original solution, I found out that directly running the `Teams.exe` file was not a good solution, as it has the potential to corrupt the installation of Microsoft Teams (which happened to me). As such, in order to run Teams the way the developers intended it to, I am opting to run the Program's shortcut file (i.e. the "Microsoft Teams.lnk" file in the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\` folder). Upon inspecting this `.lnk` file, I found that it contained additional logic and calls to MS Teams' `Update.exe` file that help prevent these issues from occurring. So, the new `Run` code to start MS Teams would be

```
run "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Teams.lnk"
```

---

With that out of the way, we can now integrate this new `run` command back into OP's program. From what I could understand of the original code, these were the objectives OP was trying to code (if any of these are incorrect, please lmk and I can update):

1. If Teams is running and the currently active window, minimize it.
2. If Teams is running, but not the active window, make it the active window
3. If Teams is not running, run it and make the active window once it opens.

So, we can effectively boil down the logic to be something like this (in pseudocode):

```
If Teams is running
   If Teams is the Active Window
      Minimize Teams
   Else (i.e. Teams is NOT the Active Window)
      Make Teams the Active Window
Else (i.e. Teams is NOT running)
   Run Teams
   Wait until Teams is done opening
   Make Teams the Active Window
```

---

Let's start with the code to detect if Teams is running. Currently, the source code uses this to try to detect is Teams is active: `If WinExist("Teams ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow")`. Ignoring whether or not this syntax is correct (I've never seen both a WinTitle and `ahk_class` parameter used in the same `""` block for WinExist), using the ahk_class, at least in this case, might not be the best option available. In the the `Windows Spy` screenshot that OP kindly provided, we can see the `ahk_exe` of `Teams.exe` would be much more specific than the `ahk_class` of `Chrome_WidgetWin_1`. As such, can use `If WinExist("ahk_exe Teams.exe")` instead for this program to detect if MS Teams is already running.

---

The next thing I want to touch on is that when Teams is "closed" i.e. by clicking the `X` button in the upper right corner of the screen or even when closed using the `WinClose` command, it's default behaviour actually minimizes it to the tray, from where the `WinActivate` command can be used maximize it, similar to how it would be if it was instead minimized to the taskbar by clicking the `-` button instead. As such, depending on personal preference, you can have Teams either minimize to the taskbar or minimize to the tray and still work the same functionally with the rest of the program. Although this was not a requested or mentioned feature by OP, I feel like this is still a useful behaviour to mention/ include in this response.

---

Next, the original code that the original script was using to Activate a non-active but still running MS Teams was as follows:

```
    Else
    {
        WinGet, winState, MinMax
        If (winState = -1)
        {
            WinRestore
            WinActivate
        }
    }
```

While the additional checks and logic that OP implemented could be useful in some scenarios, I feel like it could effectively be shortened and replaced with just a simple

```
    Else
        WinActivate
```

---

The last change I made that deviated from the original script was just the bit that ran Teams if it was not already open. I feel like I've already discussed the changes enough above, but in summary: `run ahk_exe Teams.exe` was replaced with `run "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Teams.lnk"`

---

Final Code:

```
F11::
If WinExist("ahk_exe Teams.exe") 
{
    IfWinActive
        WinMinimize ;Use this if you want to minimize Teams to the Taskbar
        ;WinClose ;Use this if you want to minimize Teams to the Tray
    Else
        WinActivate
}
Else 
{
    run "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Teams.lnk"
    WinWait, Teams
    WinActivate
}
return
```

This was a bit longer than usual, but I hope this was helpful. Once again, if you have any Questions/ Comments/ Concerns, or just want more clarification, feel free to ask.

Comment: You can replace `[YOUR USER NAME HERE]` with `%A_UserName%` which will pull the currently logged-in user's name from Windows. Just concatenate the string together with the variable like `C:\Users\%A_UserName%\appdata\local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe`

Comment: This solution seems to only work if the app is not currently running. How can you use this with `IfWinExist()` and `WinRestore()` to bring up the currently running window?

Comment: I updated my solution to integrate with your original code. While I was doing that, I realized my original solution was unsafe and ended up corrupting my installation of Teams. I am extremely grateful that you asked a follow-up that required me to revisit this code; otherwise this could have slipped under the radar and broke other ppl's Teams in the future. But in any case, if you have any more follow-ups, please lmk!